# R equivalent for tikzDevice but for pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, r, tikzdevice

I use R for producing some graphics (with R base). Thereafter to better adjust the R graphics to use in LaTex I export the R plots with the tikzDevice library. Something like, e.g.:
`tikz('sk0.tex', width = 3, height = 4)`

Recently, I started using pstricks (LaTex) and I wonder if there's a way to export R plots to the pstricks format?

Do you know if that is possible? or make sense?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there is a library, but maybe there is and I didn't look long enough. A variation of this is possible, i.e., create a PSTricks graphic using PSTricks commands, but have the data values, axis range etc. supplied by R (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894851/can-i-include-pstricks-code-in-r-exams-with-exams2pdf-and-exams2moodle-output). Of course this means you are limited by the types of graphs that PSTricks can create natively.

Comment: I do not have the answer, but I recommend to separate the generation of the data (e.g. R, Matlab, Mathematica, C++, whatever) with the graph formatting (in LaTeX). That would mean exporting the data in a txt file (or equivalent) and the using `pgfplots` (or `pstricks`) to read these files.

Comment: @anderstood I don't know how much of an R user you are, but the capabilities of R's `ggplot2` are a much more practical choice than using `pgfplots` in my experience. If you use LuaLaTeX then font matching (one of the purported advantages of using  TikZ to generate plots) is simply a non-issue.

Comment: show the structure of the R data file and it should be possible to convert the data values.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm not a R user. But I use pgfplots quite often, for various types of graphs/animations, and I find it very useful to uncouple data generation and data visualisation. Now, if `ggplot2` provides functionalities that overcome those of `pgfplots` (for instance), which is a situation I never faced in 2D, I understand. Out of curiosity, would you have an example of plot with `ggplot2` that would be difficult with `pgfplots`?

Comment: @anderstood This is not about what you can/can't do; it's about the fact that if you're using R to do data exploration and stats it makes very little sense to export data to `pgfplots` to make graphs.

Comment: @anderstood Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "generation of the data". My data comes from experiments and consists of thousands of lines of data per experiment, which is why it's simply not worth the effort to turn it into a form that is usable with `pgfplots`.